# Show message if user has entered content on page and not saved

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show a message like a popup modal if a user has entered some content and then not saved it and try to leave the page?

Something like:

[image]

This appears if you try to go to another page within Facebook BUT if you type in the URL then you get a native alert box like:

[image]

1.) What is the difference? Is the alert something that is built into browsers?

2.) How can I use jQuery to create my own custom modal boxes when similar events happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery for this, I would attach the default values to each elements data holder, then using the onbeforeunload code above check all the current values against the stored original values... An example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formID input').each(function() {

        $(this).data('original', $(this).val());

    });
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload, true);
$(".submit").click(function(){
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload, true);

});
```

THEN:

```
function beforeUnload(e) {
    $('#formID input').each(function() {

        if($(this).data('original') != $(this).val()) {
            return "You have unsaved changes!";
        }

    });
}
```

This code will work for INPUT tags, You would have to modify it to do similar checks against textarea and select elements as needed.

Comment: For the modal popup how too there are plugins ready made for you to use, just google "jquery modal window" for lists of available plugins. The difference between the two is that for some reason on that site they catch the url/page change differently than they are catching the back button, and then handling them in a different manner. I'm not sure why as I assume they could be both programmed to use a modal window... maybe the back button catch is the only one that works cross-browser with a modal window instead of the native alert. You'll have to play with it and see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt){

    //Show you custom confirm dialog box here
    //Inside the confirm dialog box if the use say YES leave the page
    //Then you should set `window.onbeforeunload` to null and
    //redirect to required location so that it will not ask again.
    var dialog = $('#confirmDialog').dialog('open');

    //This will prevent the default dialog box of the browser.
    return false;
}
```

See the [MSDN article on onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Cameron - Take a look at this.

Comment: -1, This will simply show the dialog box every time the user leaves the page, even if there are no unsaved changes.

Comment: @thedaian - This is just an example for user to explain how to show the custom dialog box while leaving the page. Off course it should be done conditionally. Make yourself clear before down voting to any answer.

Comment: @thedaian - After you understood this, care to remove your down vote?